# Is there a way to save crawled information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler, average

The user of my application submits a request via a form and receives a set of numbers. The numbers constantly update throughout the day and I need a way to track the average of the last two numbers.

It'll work something like this:

- How much experience do you have now?: 13000000
- How much experience do you have now?: 13200000 (one hour later)
- Then the user should be redirected to a page where the "experience per hour" is displayed: 200000

My application can currently only make the request for the number. Now I need a way to save that number and the time it was created, allow for a second number to be searched, and then perform a computation on them.

Here are the contents of my files.

home.html.erb with the form:

```
<h1>Welcome to xpTrack</h1>

<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:username, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:username) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

This form passes the username the user enters into `params[:username]` in the controller:

```
SearchController

class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def home
    require 'open-uri'

    @username = params[:username]
    @url = "http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=#{@username}"
    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))

    @stats = @doc.text.split(' ').map{|a| a.split(",") }

    @skills = %w(overall, attack, defence, strength, constitution, ranged, prayer, magic, cooking, woodcutting, fletching, fishing, firemaking, crafting, smithing, mining, herblore, agility, thieving, slayer, farming, runecrafting, hunter, construction, summoning, dungeoneering, divination)

    @max = 13034431
  end
end
```

This view is rendered after searching:

```
<h1>
  <%= @username.capitalize %>
</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Skill</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>Experience</th>
    <th>Experience to 99</th>
  </tr>
  <% @skills.each_with_index do |skill, i| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= skill.chomp(',').capitalize %></td>
      <td><%= @stats[i][0] %></td>
      <td><%= @stats[i][1] %></td>
      <td><%= @stats[i][2] %></td>

      <% if @stats[i][2].to_i < @max %>
      <td><%= @max - (@stats[i][2]).to_i %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Link to the application at Heroku: http://runescapecalc.herokuapp.com/

When searching, use the username 'Brink'.

Comment: Do you have a sample username to just check the output and can you explain a little bit more on what exactly you need?

Comment: Yes. I'll even deploy this to Heroku so you can check it out. Give me a few minutes. The sample username you'll use is 'Brink'.

Comment: @AnirudhanJ - I've updated the bottom of the original post with the application. After typing 'Brink' into the username form, you'll see a set of numbers. That's what I need to save and use for a later calculation.

Comment: You need to find average for all those numbers?  Also do you have access to any key value store like redis?

Comment: I think I need to provide some context. Those numbers you see represent a player's experience points. As the player plays the game throughout the day, those numbers change. I want to see how efficiently the player is playing by tracking his experience per hour. Does that make sense?

I'm not sure what a key value store or redis is.

Comment: I'd save the information to a database. Which one is up to you, but that's their reason for existence. It's trivial to store the data, to do statistics since DBMs provide those nicely, and then to delete it later. Rails makes it easy to interface with databases via Active Record, and all decent tutorials show how to do that.

Comment: Hey, @theTinMan - Thanks for your suggestion. Do you have any links to those tutorials?

Comment: Read the Rails Guide "[Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)".

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?